# Remove part of a character vector in r

Tags: r, quantmod

I am running the following

```
# rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))  #It's more courteous to make that as a comment.

library(quantmod)
symbols <- c("HOG", "GE", "GOOG")

for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {   
  getFinancials(symbols[i], src="yahoo", auto.assign = TRUE)
}
```

Which download balance sheet information for 3 firms in `symbols`. However when I call the `getFinancials` function it creates an addition to the list name. For example `GOOG.f`. I have two questions.

Question 1: How can I first remove the `.f` part from the list. 
Question 2: If I want to keep the `.f` (as removing it will cause conflicts if I want to use `getSymbols` how can I write a new `symbols` character value but with the addition to `.f`

For example `symbols.f <- c("HOC.f", "GOOG.f", "GE.f")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0` to add the .f and `sub` to take it off.

```
symbols <- c("HOG", "GE", "GOOG")

( symbols.f <- paste0(symbols, ".f") )
[1] "HOG.f"   "GE.f" "GOOG.f"

sub("\\.f","", symbols.f)  #Periods (regex metacharacter) need to be double escaped.
[1] "HOC"  "GOOG" "GE"
```

Comment: Is there something about the quantmod envirinment that makes the used of just `paste0` incorrect?  `symbols.f <- paste0(symbols, ".f")`

Comment: No,  that would be better.  Edited.